# Magento2 - How to check all running CRON Jobs?

Tags: magento2, cron, schedule

In `Magento2` how to check all running `CRON` Jobs.

Is there any way for that?

Comment: Please add more details. It's not sufficient details to understand your question.

Comment: Log in to the Magento database on the command line and enter SELECT * from cron_schedule;.

Comment: @Rohan Hapani Is there any way to get all CRON jobs running in my Magento Project?

Comment: Check cron_schedule table in database where you can able to see that all schedule cron job.

Comment: Thaks @Nikola that works fine

Comment: Add it as answer please

Comment: @PrasadD.Warnakulasuriya Done. You can marked an answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to the Magento database on the command line and enter SELECT * from cron_schedule;.